# Read article properties in Joomla 1.7 view

Tags: php, joomla1.7

I try to read an article's show_title attribute in a Joomla 1.7.3 Featured Article override using

```
$params = &$this->item->params;
$params->get('show_title');
```

There are two featured articles with different settings. One article is configures to display the title, the other one to not display the title. The global settings are "Display the title". Both articles are uncategorised.

Using the above code in template_name/html/com_content/featured/default_item.php returns the same value (1) for both articles. Why would that be?
BTW, this also happens without the template override. The article properties are correctly stored in the database.
Thanks for any insight,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: Kevin Griffiths pointed out on the Joomla issue tracker board that the Home menu item needs to be set to "Use Article Settings". Otherwise the global settings overrule the article settings.